Using dport a a variable in nftables
I have this rule in nft:
tcp dport {80, 8080, 443} accept comment "Accepted traffic from port $dport"

But the part from $dport is not working. Is there any global variable in nftables in order to know which dport is using?

It does not seem possible to achieve this, but I do not see a use case for it either.
A comment is intended to be additional information for an administrator reading the rule - when doing so, they will already see the ports involved in the rule, making a comment containing them redundant.
If you are trying to record a port being accepted, you probably want to use a log statement, where a custom message can be added using the prefix parameter. Including a port in log prefix is redundant too, as the kernel log message containing it will always have the source and destination ports as part of the log line anyways.
tcp dport {80, 8080, 443} log prefix "Accepted traffic " accept

Will make for a line similar to
[$host] Accepted traffic ... SPT=xxx DPT=xxx ...

where DPT indicates the destination port, and SPT the source port. There are other fields which I truncated as not relevant to the question.

Replace comment for log. It's the same case: you want to display the port in which traffic is established.

Can you please, put references of this "It does not seem possible to achieve this"

When using log, the ports are already logged along with other data, regardless of the message you are specifying.
